# Show that $\gcd(x^{p^n} - x , x^{p^d} - x ) = x^{p^{\gcd(n,d)}}-x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

Let $n,d$ be positive integers and $p$ a positive prime number.

How can I show that:
$$
\gcd(x^{p^n} - x , x^{p^d} - x ) = x^{p^{\gcd(n,d)}} - x
$$

Can someone at least give me some hint? I'm kinda lost at the moment.

Here's where I've got:

Suppose w.l.o.g that $n > d$, because if $n=d$ than the result is trivial. Therefore $n = qd + r$. Hence:
$$
x^{p^n} = x^{p^{qd + r}} = x^{p^{qd}} x^{p^{r}} \implies x^{p^n} - x = x^{p^{qd}} x^{p^{r}} - x
$$
(✰) Now if there's a way to show that:
$$
x^{p^n} - x = q(x)\big(x^{p^d} - x \big) + x^{p^r} - x
$$
Then it would follow that
$$
\gcd(x^{p^n} - x , x^{p^d} - x) = \gcd(x^{p^d} - x , x^{p^r} - x)
$$
Then we would have a relation between eculidean algorithm with the integers $n$ and $d$ and the polynomials, so the result would be analogous, i.e, $x^{p^{\gcd(n,d)}} - x$.

I'm actually stuck at (✰).

I've been trying to show that for hours but still can't figure it out... Thanks.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2822914/confused-by-induction-on-maxn-m-in-proof-of-gcdtn-1-tm-1-t-gcdn?rq=1 applied twice

Comment: @Exodd Thanks! That worked!